# Summing up till a certain interval

Tags: matlab

How can I compute the summation of an interval. I will use Matlab's code for eg.

```
data=[1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12]
```

I would like to perform this summation.

```
sum(1)=data(1)+data(2)+data(3)
sum(2)=data(4)+data(5)+data(6)
sum(3)=data(7)+(data(8)+data(9)
sum(4)=data(10)+data(11)+data(12)
```

How can I get about this? (Using for loop)

Comment: please avoid using `sum` for a variable name, as this will overwrite the (rather important) built-in matlab function `sum` http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/sum.html.

Answer (score 7):

No *for loop* needed, if indeed this interval is constant like in your example:

```
Ans=sum(reshape(data,3,[]))
```

note that I [reshape](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) the vector `data` to a matrix that has the right number of columns, so the value `3` relates to the interval size you wanted...

Comment: Using the variable name `Ans` is asking for trouble, too readily confused with the built-in `ans`. Especially so in advice to a neophyte.

Comment: that why in it with a capital A, besides that `ans` is anyway being produced and rewritten often...