# Sum every n rows of matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum, row

Is there any way that I can sum up columns values for each group of three rows in a matrix?
I can sum three rows up in a manual way.

For example

```
% matrix is the one I wanna store the new data.
% data is the original dataset.
matrix(1,1:end) = sum(data(1:3, 1:end))
matrix(2,1:end) = sum(data(4:6, 1:end))
...
```

But if the dataset is huge, this wouldn't work.
Is there any way to do this automatically without loops?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Summing up till a certain interval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399491/summing-up-till-a-certain-interval)

Comment: Doesn't look like a dupe to me, as it's not clear to me that a single simple reshape will do the trick.

Comment: I disagree,  a single reshape then sum and squeeze will do. The only difference vs the other question is that it is 2D vs 1D. Here's a solution: `squeeze(sum(reshape(a,size(a,2), 3,[])))`

Comment: But just for Amro's answer, this question was worth it... +1 Amro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one-liner `reshape`s so that all the values needed for a particular cell are in a column, does the `sum`, and then `reshape`s the back to the expected shape.

```
reshape(sum(reshape(data, 3, [])), [], size(data, 2))
```

The naked `3` could be changed if you want to sum a different number of rows together. It's on you to make sure the number of rows in each group divides evenly.

Comment: wow~ this one is pretty cool. It works well! Matlab rocks! Thanks a lot. @Prashant

Answer (score 5):

Here are four other ways:

1. The obligatory `for`-loop:

   ```
   % for-loop over each three rows
   matrix = zeros(size(data,1)/3, size(data,2));
   counter = 1;
   for i=1:3:size(data,1)
       matrix(counter,:) = sum(data(i:i+3-1,:));
       counter = counter + 1;
   end
   ```
2. Using `mat2cell` for tiling:

   ```
   % divide each three rows into a cell
   matrix = mat2cell(data, ones(1,size(data,1)/3)*3);

   % compute the sum of rows in each cell
   matrix = cell2mat(cellfun(@sum, matrix, 'UniformOutput',false));
   ```
3. Using third dimension (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1390909/97160)):

   ```
   % put each three row into a separate 3rd dimension slice
   matrix = permute(reshape(data', [], 3, size(data,1)/3), [2 1 3]);

   % sum rows, and put back together
   matrix = permute(sum(matrix), [3 2 1]);
   ```
4. Using `accumarray`:

   ```
   % build array of group indices [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,...]
   idx = floor(((1:size(data,1))' - 1)/3) + 1;

   % use it to accumulate rows (appliead to each column separately)
   matrix = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(i)accumarray(idx,data(:,i)), 1:size(data,2), ...
       'UniformOutput',false));
   ```

Of course all the solution so far assume that the number of rows is evenly divisble by `3`.

Comment: The answers are really helpful. Each of them is a nice example to learn. Appreciate this. @Amro

Comment: Actually, I've noticed that there is another problem. What if the number of rows isn't divisible. Don't know how to solve it. I just delete some data to make the number divisible. Do you have experienced ideas? Amro?

Comment: @ChrisSu: I added a 4th solution: a simple for-loop. You should not be so quick to discard it, it is also comparatively fast (thanks to JIT compilation in MATLAB)

Comment: @ChrisSu: in that case just process `data(1:3*N,:)` where `N = floor(size(data,1)/3)` as before, then add whatever is left (sum of the remaining one or two rows). Of course all these solution can be generalized to work with any group of `X` rows (we had X=3 for the above)

Comment: The 4th solution is good. Loop is ok, but it's still a C or java mind to program. Since I'm new to matlab, I wanna train myself to understand the essence better. About the in-divisible problem, I think you are right. May pre-calculate of N would be better than my solution. Appreciate your detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Slice the matrix into three pieces and add them together:

```
matrix = data(1:3:end, :) + data(2:3:end, :) + data(3:3:end, :);
```

This will give an error if `size(data,1)` is not a multiple of three, since the three pieces wouldn't be the same size.  If appropriate to your data, you might work around that by truncating `data`, or appending some zeros to the end.

You could also do something fancy with `reshape` and 3D arrays.  But I would prefer the above (unless you need to replace `3` with a variable...)

Comment: Yea. I see what you mean. This works if the required pieces is small. Actually, it may grow up to 140 pieces. In that case, this way wouldn't work through. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Prashant answered nicely before but I would have a simple amendment:

```
fl = filterLength;
A = yourVector (where mod(A,fl)==0)
sum(reshape(A,fl,[]),1).'/fl;
```

There is the ",1" that makes the line run even when fl==1 (original values).
I discovered this while running it in a for loop like so:

```
... read A ...
% Plot data
hold on;

averageFactors = [1 3 10 30 100 300 1000];
colors = hsv(length(averageFactors));
clear legendTxt;


for i=1:length(averageFactors)
% ------ FILTERING ----------
clear Atrunc;
clear ttrunc;
clear B;
fl = averageFactors(i); % filter length
Atrunc = A(1:L-mod(L,fl),:);
ttrunc = t(1:L-mod(L,fl),:);

B = sum(reshape(Atrunc,fl,[]),1).'/fl;
tB = sum(reshape(ttrunc,fl,[]),1).'/fl;
length(B)
plot(tB,B,'color',colors(i,:) )
%kbhit ()
endfor
```