# Making a matrix out of vectors in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, matrix

If I have vectors of equal length (A, B, and C for example), how can I put them in a matrix (A, B, C) in MATLAB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If they are row vectors: `[A; B; C]` or `[A; B; C].'`. The `.'` is matrix transposition.

If they are column vectors: `[A, B, C]` or `[A, B, C].'`.

If they can be either colmuns or rows: `[A(:), B(:), C(:)]` or `[A(:), B(:), C(:)].'`. The `(:)` tranforms into a column vector.

Comment: Is possible to implement this is a loop because I have thousands of vectors?

Comment: Sure. But you should give us more information. In any case, you should try to [preallocate](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/techniques-for-improving-performance.html) the matrices

Comment: Okay so I have a very long vector (ex time series) and a find function that locates events (specific indexes in the time series) in this long vector. What I am doing is taking the events and looking at history 150 steps before the event and then averaging all the histories. My idea was to create a matrix of all these vectors such that I can do the averaging.

Comment: `reshape` will do... see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399491/summing-up-till-a-certain-interval/17399540#17399540 for a starting point and replace the sum with mean...

Comment: @Shagster_84 If natan's advice is not enough for you, I suggest you post a new question (with example variables defined)

Comment: @LuisMendo I don't need to reshape it but to add onto it. An idea is to add each small vector with a loop because within the loop I have to change the index of the small vector within the large one. I'm stuck in writing the syntax.